# Deployment Target in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4.2

Using Xcode 4.2, I created an app with deployment target set as 3.2. I was able to install the app on an iPad with iOS5. But when I tried to install the app in iPhone 3G with iOS4.2, it is not installing properly.It shows "Build Succeed" and immediately shows "finished running in iPhone", but not getting installed. It is working fine in all simulators. I tried installing the file by creating app.ipa file, and dragging it to iTunes, but it is showing that it is not compatible with the iPhone. Does anyone have any ideas on how to help, or test this situation properly? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

deployment target as 3.2 is iPad. I could not recall any iPhone OS version as 3.2 . It was 3.1.3 later on it was 4.0(iPhone) release with 3.2 (iPad).

I'm sure if you set your deployment target as 4.0, it will work.

best of luck..!!

Comment: Thank u for the quick response...let me make a try.